# Export C library to Windows dll

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

So I have source code written in C for the LibIdn2 library. I am looking to port it into C# but running in to some issues along the way and would appreciate some help.

- Installed Cygwin along with Make and GCC G++ packages
- Successfully able to run the./configure command on the source directory
- After this, running the "make" command produces an .exe file.

I have been trying to get a .dll file created but cannot seem to do so using gcc compiler. The command I am running is:

```
gcc -shared -o idn2.dll src/idn2.c
```

but it complains that it cant find the header files referenced in the idn2.c source file.

I have checked that in the idn2.h file, dll_Export is defined.

Any ideas how should I proceed? I need to get a dll.

Comment: I'm confused.  You say you want to *port* C code to C#, but it sounds like you're just trying to build a Windows version of a C library (which maybe you hope to call from C#).  These are entirely different things.

Comment: My apologies..you are correct. I am trying to build a windows version of a c library. What I will eventually do once I get a dll is to build a C# wrapper

Comment: Well which header files is it looking for?

Comment: Hi Mark. Its complaining about config.h, which i am sure is because its the first one referenced. I tried providing the directory path for GCC to search using the switch gcc -B "directory path", but the header files are in different directories, if I am making any sense

Comment: The libidn2 docs say that [it depends on GNU Unistring and GNU iconv](https://gitlab.com/libidn/libidn2#dependencies), which you did not mention.  If the compiler cannot find needed headers, then my first guess would be that it is headers for those separate libraries that it is looking for.

Comment: Hi John. In the source directory I do have those header files under different folders. Should not gcc be able to link the header files if a source path is provided?

Comment: You should not try to run `gcc` directly to build an Autotools project, nor generally any project that relies on `make`.  You might make it work, but the whole point of a `Makefile` is to record all the needed build details -- not just dependencies, but also compilation flags and many other things.

Comment: GCC will find the third-party headers if they are installed in its search path (unclear whether this is the case) or if you specify their location(s) via an `-I` option (not shown in your `gcc` command).  But these are some of the things that `configure` + `make` should help you with, and some of the reasons not to run `gcc` directly to build a project such as this.

Comment: I see. Pardon my ignorance on this topic. I have been able to get an .exe using the "make" command after running ./Configure on source. Is there a switch or a flag I can set to produce a dll?

Comment: If the makefile doesn't have an .so target, then you'll have to create one. Sounds like the dependencies are not very simple, though. If this is an Autotools makefile, you're more likely to break it by editing it manually. If it does have an .so target, try specifying that target when you call `make`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Managed to get a dll by using the following command `./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32`. However, the dll seems to not be a valid image. it doesnt have a manifest. Is there some setting I can toggle in the MakeFile that will produce a manifest file as well?